# Autocorrelation of a Wiener Process proof

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Given a Wiener process X, how do I prove this?

$R_x(s,t) = E[X(s)X(t)] = min(s,t)$

There seems to be a trick with dividing to two cases of $s<t$ and $s>t$, but I can't figure out how this would be helpful.

This is what I've got so far:

$R_x(s,t) = E[X(s)X(t)] = E[X(s)(X(t)-X(s)+X(s))]$
$=E[X(s)^2]+E[X(s)(X(t)-X(s)]=E[X(s)^2]+E[(X(s)-X(0))(X(t)-X(s)]$
$=E[X(s)^2]+E[(X(s)-X(0))]E[(X(t)-X(s)]$
$=E[X(s)^2]+E[(X(s))]E[(X(t)-X(s)] = E[X(s)^2] = Var[X(s)] = s$

But the same thing could be done with t instead of s... So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Be sure to provide thorough background or your own work to avoid having your questions prematurely closed!

Comment: @Ana Mzmz:  You edited with the proof as I was posting -- the argument is symmetric with respect to $s$ and $t$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brownian motion has independent increments and $X(t) \sim N(0,t)$.

If $t < s$ then

$$0 = E[X(t)(X(s)-X(t))] = E[X(t)X(s)]-E[X(t)^2]=E[X(t)X(s)]-t.$$

Hence,

$$E[X(t)X(s)]  = t = \min(t,s)$$

Similarly if $s < t$, then $E[X(t)X(s)]  = s = \min(t,s)$

Comment: I still don't understand the importance of assuming $t<s$.
What's wrong with the following, for example?

Assume $s<t$. So $0=E[X(t)(X(s)−X(t))]=E[X(t)X(s)]−E[X(t))^2]$, hence $E[X(t)(X(s)]=t \neq min(t,s)$

Comment: That is incorrect because if $s < t$ then $t = \max(t,s)$. Furthermore $X(t)-X(0)$ and $X(s)-X(t)$ are not independent in this case -- the increments overlap.

Comment: Thank you! The overlapping explanation is what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome.