# How to determine if a function is a correlation function of a process?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884299/autocorrelation-of-a-wiener-process-proof) page shows the corralation function of Wiener process X is $R(s,t)=\min (s,t)$.

I've learned how to compute the corralation function of a process, but now encountered an inverse problem: to determined if a function is a corralation function of some process.

The problem gives $f(s,t)=\min{(s,t)}$ as an example. Surely I know that it is a corralation function referring to the page mentioned, but what if I don't know (or cannot find) the original process? Is there and procedure to determine this?

Comment: Correlation functions are non-negative definite.

Comment: Therefore if a function is non-negative definite, could I say that it must be a correlation function?

Comment: See Theorem 1.2.3 in Ash and Gardner, Stochastic Processes.

Comment: Thank you! I found it.